# Establish connection of Qlik Sense with Python

Tags: python, qliksense

I am looking to establish Qlik Sense connection with Python with the main intention of being able to load QVDs in Python. Is that possible ? There is very limited documentation available online regarding the same

Comment: Did you look at [this](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/Call-the-Qlik-Sense-QRS-API-with-Python/ta-p/1715877)?

Comment: What do you mean by "load QVDs in Python?" Do you mean you want to use Python to kick off reloads in Qlik Sense for apps that generate QVDs? Or do you mean you want to read the data from QVD files using Python?

Comment: I want to read the data from QVD files using Python . Actually there are multiple QVDs stored in a folder (same format) and I simply want to read those in Python as perform analysis in Python as I am more familiar with Python and QVDs are also of large format so would read it through PySpark

Comment: Make sure you're marking answers as correct or clarifying why they aren't correct. It helps  others who may have similar questions

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read QVDs with Python, you can use the [`qvd` Python library](https://pypi.org/project/qvd/) created by Sam Bentley. I personally haven't used it but it appears to achieve exactly what you want.

If that library doesn't work for you for any reason, you could probably write your own with medium effort. [QVD files](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/Scripting/work-with-QVD-files.htm#anchor-4) are XML based and are comprised of (1) metadata, (2) a byte-stuffed symbol table, and (3) a bit-stuffed data table. If you've ever worked with bits, bytes, and their associated Python functions and operators, then you could roll this on your own.

If neither of those options are viable, you could get creative by using Python to make API calls to the Qlik to (1) create a session app, (2) set the script to load the QVDs in question, (3) kick off the app reload, (4) create a session table object with all QVD data, and then (5) page through the hypercube to get all of the data. If you use Qlik SaaS then you can utilize Qlik's own [Python SDK library](https://pypi.org/project/qlik-sdk/). Otherwise you can use a third party library like [`qSense`](https://pypi.org/project/qsense/) created by Matteo Redaelli. If you want to make your own Qlik API call functions using the Python `requests` library, then you can refer to the QRS API docs [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2023/APIs/RepositoryServiceAPI/index.html) and the JSON API docs [here](https://qlik.dev/apis/json-rpc/qix#docs).

Comment: I am not a technical guy so what you said above just was beyond my understanding. However, it did try to give this to an expert in Data Engineer and he had a hard time extracting data and his final assessment was it is not possible to extract the tabular part from qvd files